# Oracle SQL developer - why I cannot delete the row from the tables that I set on delete cascade and get an invalid table name error?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using `Oracle SQL Developer`, below is the error I get:

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00903: invalid table name
>   00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"

Here is my code:

```
ALTER TABLE PCASE
  DROP CONSTRAINT PCASE_Participant_FK;

ALTER TABLE PCASE
  ADD CONSTRAINT PCASE_Participant_FK
  FOREIGN KEY ( PartID )
  REFERENCES Participant ( PartID )
  ON DELETE CASCADE;


ALTER TABLE Meeting
  DROP CONSTRAINT Meeting_PCASE_FK;

ALTER TABLE Meeting
  ADD CONSTRAINT Meeting_PCASE_FK
  FOREIGN KEY ( PCaseNo )
  REFERENCES PCASE ( PCaseNo )
  ON DELETE CASCADE; 


ALTER TABLE MPlan
  DROP CONSTRAINT MPlan_Meeting_FK;

ALTER TABLE MPlan
  ADD CONSTRAINT MPlan_Meeting_FK
  FOREIGN KEY ( PCaseNo, MeetingNo )
  REFERENCES Meeting ( PCaseNo, MeetingNo )
  ON DELETE CASCADE; 


ALTER TABLE Laboratory
  DROP CONSTRAINT Laboratory_MPlan_FK; 

ALTER TABLE Laboratory
  ADD CONSTRAINT Laboratory_MPlan_FK
  FOREIGN KEY ( MPlanNo )
  REFERENCES MPlan ( MPlanNo )
  ON DELETE CASCADE; 


ALTER TABLE Diary
  DROP CONSTRAINT Diary_MPlan_FK; 

ALTER TABLE Diary
  ADD CONSTRAINT Diary_MPlan_FK
  FOREIGN KEY ( MPlanNo )
  REFERENCES MPlan ( MPlanNo )
  ON DELETE CASCADE; 

COMMIT;

SELECT * 
  FROM Participant
  WHERE PartID=12345;

DELETE * 
  FROM Participant
  WHERE PartID=12345;
```

I just set the `FKs` of the child tables as ON `DELETE CASCADE`, but it does not work.
I tried another method as below, but get the same error.

```
DELETE *
FROM Participant p, PCASE pc, Meeting m, MPlan mp, Laboratory l
WHERE p.PartID=pc.PartID
AND pc.PCaseNo=m.PCaseNo
AND (m.PCaseNo=mp.PCaseNo
    AND m.MeetingNo=mp.MeetingNo)
AND mp.MPlanNo=l.MPlanNo 
AND p.PartID=12345;


DELETE *
FROM Participant p, PCASE pc, Meeting m, MPlan mp, Diary d
WHERE p.PartID=pc.PartID
AND pc.PCaseNo=m.PCaseNo
AND (m.PCaseNo=mp.PCaseNo
    AND m.MeetingNo=mp.MeetingNo)
AND mp.MPlanNo=d.MPlanNo
AND p.PartID=12345;
```

Can anybody help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you also using MySQL , Microsoft SQL Server ?

Comment: You state `Here is my code:` but nowhere in that code do you create any tables so it is not surprising that you get an invalid table name.

Comment: Hi i'm using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: sorry, I just omitted the create table codes

Answer (score 1):

It's `DELETE FROM ...`, not `DELETE * FROM ...`. Your invalid syntax is confusing Oracle's parser into giving you a slightly misleading error message.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured out that is the reason.